# Swagger Model Schema does not include variable name for body parameter

Tags: java, json, swagger, swagger-ui

In the Swagger UI for my application I have POST and PUT methods that both take in a POJO as a body parameter in the REST call. When I look at the UI and click on the Model Schema to automatically fill the parameter box (just to save time on typing the whole JSON out) it does not include the name of the parameter so the request fails. Example:

Model Schema:

```
{ 
   "first": "string",
   "last": "string",
   "address": "string",
   "email": "string",
   .
   .
   .
}
```

However, to make the request I need to include the parameter name `entry` as so:

```
{ "entry": {
   "first": "string",
   "last": "string",
   "address": "string",
   "email": "string",
   .
   .
   .
}}
```

While it is not too inconvenient to do this myself before making a request, it has caused issues with other developers using the Swagger UI for my application and not realizing that they need to add `entry`. Is there a way to modify the Model Schema?

Answer (score 2):

The `name` of the parameter is not used as a property in `body` parameter. In order to describe your model, you can define a `entry` property with `object` type as follow:

```
definitions:
  Entry:
    type: object
    properties:
      entry:
        type: object
        properties:
          first: 
            type: string
          last:
            type: string
          address:
            type: string
          email:
            type: string
```

and you can use it as body schema like follows:

```
post:
  produces:
    - application/json
  parameters:
    - name: body
      in: body
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Entry'
```

Comment: Put it under `definitions` and use it as the body schema.

Comment: Is there an annotation that would automatically create the correct hierarchy?

Comment: [Swagger-Core Annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations)? [@ApiModel](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apimodel) should work.

Comment: I added `ApiModel(value = "entry")` to the Entry class but that did not add "entry" to the model schema on Swagger

Comment: Is your `Entry` class used as parameter in api operation? like `User` in this [code sample](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiparam)

Comment: Yes, and I have `required = true` for it, just like the example.

Comment: Seems that I misunderstand your meaning of "automatically create the correct hierarchy". Try `@JsonRootName(value = "entry")` in Entry class and see whether can help.